# CURL: not fetching url with unicode characters

Tags: php, curl

I'm using CURL to fetch a Yahoo! BOSS api url with a unicode query, but I'm getting an "bad request" error.

```
http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/கமல்ஹாசன்?appid={appid}&format=xml
```

The above url works fine and returns results in firefox.

Please could anybody help me to fix this.

```
$url = "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/கமல்ஹாசன்?appid={appid}&format=xml";

$ch - curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Why not `urlencode` the unicode part?

Answer (score 2):

you must urlencode your URL.
follow the below codes:

```php
$url = "http://yoursite.com/some-unicode-chars"

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

if ($path) {
    $segments = explode('/', $path);
    foreach($segments as $index => $segment) {
        $segments[$index] = urlencode($segment);
    }

    $url = str_replace($path, implode('/', $segments), $url);
}

// then use url in your curl command:
$handle = curl_init($url);
// ...
```

Answer (score -8):

Take that கமல்ஹாசன் word and use 
Mysql_realescape string in PHP.

Regards,
ARCHIT.

Comment: What in god's name has mysql got to do withg URLs?!